# Undefined is not an object (evaluating this.state.name)

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have one class (User) that fetches data asynchronously and needs to return it to the other classes in my program. What would be the most efficient way to do this in React Native.

**User.Js**

```js
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { Component } from 'react';

class User extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      phone: '',
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();

    return firebase.database().ref(`/users/students/${currentUser.uid}`)
    .once('value')
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({ name: response.val().displayName });
    });
  }

  getName() {
    return this.state.name;
  }
}

export const getName = User.prototype.getName;
```

**ActivityList.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import ActivityDetail from './ActivityDetail';
import { getName } from '../../models/User';

class ActivityList extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { People: [] };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    return firebase.database().ref('/users/teachers/').once('value').then(response => this.setState({ People: response.val() }));
  }

  renderPeople() {
    console.log('rendering');
    return this.state.People.map(person => <ActivityDetail key={person.Name} person={person} />);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);

    console.log(getName().bind(this));

    return (
      <ScrollView>
        {this.renderPeople()}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

export { ActivityList };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say:

```
console.log(getName().bind(this));
```

It simply return ActivityList::state.name, which is not there. So raise the exception.

If you want you can do following, in user.js

```
function getCurrentUser() {
    const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();

    return firebase.database().ref(`/users/students/${currentUser.uid}`)
      .once('value')
      .then((response) => {
         return { name: response.val().displayName };
      });
}
```

In other class simply say:

```
getCurrentUser().then(currentUser => this.setState({name: currentUser.name});
```